# Not getting integer overflow in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojure-1.3

I am running Clojure 1.3.0 with La Clojure in IntelliJ IDEA while reading *The Joy Of Clojure*, and on section 4.1.3 (page 64), the authors demonstrate integer overflow with the following code:

```
(+ Integer/MAX_VALUE Integer/MAX_VALUE)
;=> java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow
```

However, when I try it out on the REPL, I get instead

```
user=> (+ Integer/MAX_VALUE Integer/MAX_VALUE)
4294967294

user=> Integer/MAX_VALUE
2147483647
```

What is happening here? Why are my integers being added correctly instead of overflowing?

Comment: I got that exception, are you sure..?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran I copy-pasted all that, so I am pretty sure... :O

Comment: @wrongusernaem : I'm using `1.2.0` and get that exception. Seems like book [that edition] uses `1.2.0`. And **gertalot** have the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**(edited)** Clojure (at least 1.3.0) automatically converts the integer to a long if necessary. For more details about automatic boxing, promotion and primitive numeric type support in Clojure 1.3.0 check the [Documentation for Clojure 1.3.0 Numerics](http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Documentation+for+1.3+Numerics).

The reason you don't get an overflow is because Clojure automatically converts the integer to a long, so `(+ Integer/MAX_VALUE Integer/MAX_VALUE)` is adding two longs:

```
user> (type Integer/MAX_VALUE)
java.lang.Long
```

Answer (score 8):

In Clojure **all primative integers are primative longs** and the documentation on the numerics page is refering to that. in 1.3 you just need bigger numbers to get your overflow.

```
user=> (+ Long/MAX_VALUE Long/MAX_VALUE)
ArithmeticException integer overflow  clojure.lang.Numbers.throwIntOverflow (Numbers.java:1374)
```

This important part is that older versions of clojure would have promoted to a big int automatically and it was decided that the cost of this was not worth the extremely rare cases where it is desired. if you really want promoting math use `+'`

```
user=> (+' Long/MAX_VALUE Long/MAX_VALUE)
18446744073709551614N
```