# Clojure integer overflow

Tags: clojure, jvm

I'm running Clojure 1.4.0.  Why is it if I add `Integer/MAX_VALUE` and 1, I get a Long, but if I add `Integer/MAX_VALUE` to itself, I get an exception?

```
=> (def one 1)
=> (class one)
java.lang.Integer
=> (def max-plus-one (+ Integer/MAX_VALUE one))
=> max-plus-one
2147483648
=> (class max-plus-one)
java.lang.Long

=> (+ Integer/MAX_VALUE Integer/MAX_VALUE)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Shouldn't they both act the same way?  Why does adding two `MAX_VALUE` values overflows but adding 1 doesn't?

I've seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664093/not-getting-integer-overflow-in-clojure) but they are getting different behaviour than I am.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's strange, I see different results with Clojure 1.4.0and Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_06-b24), on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit:

```
user=> *clojure-version*
{:major 1, :minor 4, :incremental 0, :qualifier nil}
user=> (+ Integer/MAX_VALUE Integer/MAX_VALUE)
4294967294
user=> (type 1)
java.lang.Long
user=> (def max-plus-one (+ Integer/MAX_VALUE one))
#'user/max-plus-one
user=> max-plus-one
2147483648
user=> (type max-plus-one)
java.lang.Long
user=> (+ Integer/MAX_VALUE Integer/MAX_VALUE)
4294967294
```

You can always check the [Java classes which clojure.core uses for numerics](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Numbers.java), to see how the functionality is implemented:

The implementation of the + operator in:

```
(defn +
  "Returns the sum of nums. (+) returns 0. Does not auto-promote
  longs, will throw on overflow. See also: +'"
  {:inline (nary-inline 'add 'unchecked_add)
   :inline-arities >1?
   :added "1.2"}
  ([] 0)
  ([x] (cast Number x))
  ([x y] (. clojure.lang.Numbers (add x y)))
  ([x y & more]
     (reduce1 + (+ x y) more)))
```

Java implementation of adding longs:

```
final public Number add(Number x, Number y){
    return num(Numbers.add(x.longValue(),y.longValue()));
}
```

Edits: Tested with Clojure 1.2.1
I have done a quick test with Clojure 1.2.1, and with that version of Clojure I get exactly your behavior.

```
user=> *clojure-version*
{:major 1, :minor 2, :incremental 1, :qualifier ""}
user=> (def one 1)
#'user/one
user=> (class 1)
java.lang.Integer
user=> (def max-plus-one (+ Integer/MAX_VALUE one))
#'user/max-plus-one
user=> max-plus-one
2147483648
user=> (class max-plus-one)
java.lang.Long
user=> (+ Integer/MAX_VALUE Integer/MAX_VALUE)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

I'd say that you did the test with Clojure 1.2.x, and not with 1.4.0. What is the value of *clojure-version* in your REPL?

Comment: You're right: `{:major 1, :minor 2, :incremental 1, :qualifier ""}`.  I have 1.4.0 installed but it appears the Sublime Text 2 REPL uses its own Clojure.

Comment: I've had a similar experience in the past, when I had multiple versions of Clojure on my machine.

Comment: Yeah it looks like the SublimeREPL plugin runs `lein repl` which is loading up Clojure 1.2.1 for some reason.

Comment: Ok, for people curious as to why the version of `lein repl` is different than your `clj` version: https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/337 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135440/lein-clojure-1-3-vs-clojure-1-2-1

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have your answer, but here are a few other interesting points:

java (all versions) and clojure's (>1.3.0) default behaviour differ in their behaviour wrt overflow

in java

```
(Long.MAX_VALUE + 1) == Long.MIN_VALUE
(Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1) == Integer.MIN_VALUE

// cast required to avoid promoting to int
(Byte.MAX_VALUE + (byte)1) == Byte.MIN_VALUE
```

This is because arithmetic wraps by default on the jvm

in clojure (>1.3.0)

```
(inc Long.MAX_VALUE) 
   => ArithmeticOverflow

(inc Integer/MAX_VALUE) 
   => a long with value Integer/MAX_VALUE + 1
(int (inc Integer/MAX_VALUE)) 
   => IllegalArgumentException Value 
      out of range for int: 2147483648
```

clojure does have versions of some ops that behave like java

```
(unchecked-inc Long.MAX_VALUE) => Long.MIN_VALUE
```

You can make the unchecked operations the default by setting `*unchecked-math*` to true

```
(set! *unchecked-math* true)
(inc Long/MAX_VALUE) 
    => (Long.MIN_VALUE)
(int (inc Integer/MAX_VALUE)) 
    => (Integer.MIN_VALUE) of type Integer
```

There are lots of other interesting `(unchecked-*)` operations.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.3.0 Clojure uses Longs for all primitive numbers. you just need to use larger numbers to get the overflow.

```
 (def max-plus-one (+ Long/MAX_VALUE one))
```

Comment: The strange thing is that (class 1) or (type 1) seems to return 'java.lang.integer' instead of long in cdmckay's case. If he's running Clojure 1.4.0, that shouldn't happen.